# Mapview delegate not calling when add Annotation in ios7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, mkmapview

I am dropping multiple pins on mapview where I need to display different Image for all pins for that I am doing the below code.

```
- (void)dropMultiplePinAnnotation:(NSArray *)arrThumbnail
{
    [self removeAnnotations:[self annotations]];

    for(Annotation *Annot in arrThumbnail) {

        self.pinImageName = Annot.PinImage;
        Annot.coordinate = Detail.coordinate;
        [self addAnnotation:Annot];
        //Till ios6, after this line viewForAnnotation gets called so that I can assign new pin image everytime but in ios7 viewforAnnotation called after this loop ends so it set pin image which was latest saved in self.pinImageName
    }    
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *AnnotViewID = @"annotViewID";
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[self dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotViewID];

    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotViewID];
    }
    annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;

    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.pinImageName];
    annotationView.annotation = annotation;

    return annotationView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code can't assume anything about when that delegate method is called, even under iOS 6 I would guess there are cases this will break.

Why not just use `[annotation PinImage]` instead of `self.pinImageName`? The annotation object passed to `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` is the same one you pass to `addAnnotation:` above.

Answer (score 0):

I am dropping multiple pins on mapview where I need to display different Image for all pins for that I am doing the below code.

```
- (void)dropMultiplePinAnnotation:(NSArray *)arrThumbnail

    {
        [self removeAnnotations:[self annotations]];

        for(Annotation *Annot in arrThumbnail) {

            self.pinImageName = Annot.PinImage;
            Annot.coordinate = Detail.coordinate;
            [self addAnnotation:Annot];
       [_mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(Annot.coordinate,      MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.004,0.004))];
            //So you can fire every time viewForAnnotation delegate after every annotation adding to MKMapView
        }    
    }

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
    {

    static NSString *AnnotViewID = @"annotViewID";
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[self dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotViewID];

        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotViewID];
        }
        annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;

        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.pinImageName];
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;

        return annotationView;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure MKMapViewDelegate is set for MKMapView object.

Can you check that?

Comment: It is getting called.So that we can identify from that it has been set